# Style not applied correct

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

This is my `Xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="35" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
</Style>
[...]
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=BirthdayDay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=0}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Days, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=BirthdayMonth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=0}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Months, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=BirthdayYear, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=0}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Years, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And the result is very confusing:

[image]

Is it somehow colliding with the `TextBlock` `Style`?
Since the `FontWeight` is applied it seems like there is a connection ?!

**NOTE:**

The only "obvious" difference I can see it that the Binding differs:

`Day + Year` is a `Collection` of `Integers` while `Month` is a `Collection` of `string`?!

Comment: Are day and year ComboBox not editable and month editable?

Comment: @nkoniishvt I dont use CodeBehind(only MVVM) so all I modiefied on Styles/Behaviour is what you see in the xaml !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the type of the data and the fact that you didn't define a way to display the data : ItemTemplate, ItemTemplateSelector or StringFormat

If you add `<Setter Property="ItemStringFormat" Value="{}{0}"></Setter>`

All ComboBoxes will display correctly.

The [ItemsControl.UpdateSelectionBoxItem](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ComboBox.cs,667a7cd66ecbac16) is the function that is in charge of displaying data in the selection box but I couldn't figure how it treated int differently from String in the process of extracting and displaying the Item.

Anyway, int are displayed as TextBlocks and String as TextBox if I get it right, and that's why you int takes your Style.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CommonStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonStyle}">
    </Style>       
</Window.Resources>
```